# Pattern for Bridging Containers -> Kubernetes deployments

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes deployment and a local developer environment running in a container. The app requires memcached, which I'd like to run in its own container and run linked. I do not want to change my application at all between development and production, I'd like the environment to do that for me. So, my problem is how do I configure my application to work properly in both environments? My thoughts:

1. Inject the variable into the app using something like Figaro. This feels heavy weight for just a few different items I'd like to configure.
2. Run a script at startup of the Docker container to rewrite the /etc/hosts, just when running on my local machine. Super hacky but easy.
3. Run using hyperkube or some other local version of Kubernetes.

Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Running Kubernetes locally is your best bet, to ensure you have the same environment in development as what you're deploying to.

We recommend running [Kubernetes locally via Docker](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md) as the best starting point for local testing.

If for some reason that doesn't work for you, let us know, but you could also try running Kubernetes locally [on Vagrant](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/vagrant.md).

Comment: Can I build and deploy locally, or do I need to push every build to a repo, and then bring it back down?

Comment: You should be able to build and deploy docker images locally if you use the recommended method.